# php include template failed on ubuntu+apache+php

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

If I ran my template locally, the template code can expand properly

```
<html>
<head>
<? include $template ?> 
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However if I ran from an apache+php, it failed to expand.

[image]

I checked the error.log under /var/log/apache2 but cannot find any error message related to this template/php file.

On my local PC (OSX), php version is  5.5.20

On the apache, php version is:

```
$ dpkg -s php5
Package: php5
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: php
Installed-Size: 29
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5
Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) | libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) | php5-cgi (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) | php5-fpm (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5), php5-common (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5)
```

Where should I start to investigate this problem?

I have zero exposure to php before.

Comment: Might be a silly mistake. Did you make sure `short_open_tag` in your `php.ini` file is set to 1?

Comment: Most installs do not allow short tags, so you need `<?php ?>` for proper syntax.

Comment: @Twisty You're right. It fixed the problem. Please turn  your comment into an answer so I can accept

Comment: @icecub Thanks for the input! Please turn your comment into an answer so I can upvote

Comment: Thanks for the upvote :) Though such simple mistakes hardly deserve getting some rep over, haha. It's simply something overlooked easily :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most installs do not allow short tags, so you need `<?php ?>` for proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

the syntax for your php short tags must contain equal sign after the opening php tag..

try this out `<?=include $template; ?>`

Comment: or you can do the `<?php ?>` suggested by Twisty.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `short_open_tag` to 1 inside `php.ini`.